# Networking has stopped working - where can I find out why?

Tags: network-interface, networkmanager, xubuntu

The XUbuntu PC in my boy's room has been working fine for years. Today, with no changes made to configuration or anything, the network no longer works.

If I check the status of the networking service it says "active(exited)". If I try to restart it I get no output to indicate anything, neither to indicate it starting or to indicate it failing. I looked in the system log and saw no sign of any errors. "ifconfig" shows the "eth0" interface present but without an IP address (unsurprisingly). I have tried commands like "ifconfig eth0 up" and so on but nothing produces any output at all.

I have Network Manager installed (apparently). I went to the GUI network settings and all the configuration looks fine. I couldn't find any buttons to disable and re-enable the interface there.

I don't know why networking has stopped working without any changes being made and after so long without problems. Worst of all I don't have any clues or any idea where else to look for clues.

Where can I look to try and find out what has gone wrong?

Comment: Does whatever is on the other side of the cable work properly? Is the cable still inserted properly or has a pet or housemate happened to pull it out?

Comment: The cable seemed fine but just in case I replaced it with a known good cable. Good clue though. Possibly the wall socket got damaged. I will test it.

Comment: I tested the wall socket and it was fardled. I opened it up and inspected it and it looked fine so I tested it again and it was fine. The networking is now working fine. I think a gremlin must have been got trapped behind the faceplate and when I opened it up he escaped.

Comment: I'd still like an answer though. There must be some log file or something somewhere that would tell me that the hardware link is faulty/not present/not working.

Comment: One more place you could probably have looked: if you use DHCP, the DHCP server (likely your router) will have a good idea on who requested IPs from it and may show that on its configuration interface.

Comment: `ip link` will tell you whether the interface has a physical connection (look for `LOWER_UP`).

Comment: Patrick, can you make that an answer so I can accept it, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Patrick's comment (he didn't make a formal answer, so I am):

`ip link` will tell you whether the interface has a physical connection (look for LOWER_UP).